# R: '...' used in an incorrect context

Tags: r, arguments, parameter-passing

I have looked at about 40 instances of this error on stackoverflow, but the example below does not appear to me to suffer from any of the defects that these other instances displayed, and I do not know what is wrong with it.

```
ob1 <-5; ob2 <- 6; ob4 <- 7; ob5 <- 8;  ob7 <- 8;
fs <- function(ob1, ob2=ob3, ..., ob4, ob5=ob6){
  `...` <- unlist(list(...))
  print(ob1, ob2, ob4, ob5, `...`)
}


f_outer <- function(){
  ob1 <-1; ob2 <- 2; ob4 <- 3; ob5 <- 4;  ob7 <- 9;
  fs(ob1, ob2=ob3, ob4, ob5=ob6, ob7)
}

f_outer()
```

Returns the error:

```
'...' used in an incorrect context
```

Comment: I'm trying to find the reference, but I'm pretty sure that `...` is reserved such that you cannot explicitly assign anything to it.  Can you save the unlisted version as `dots` and pass that?

Comment: andrewH, you've recently generated some really ... "out there" questions for R, and they're stretching my brain (not a bad thing). Is there some reason you're trying to overwrite *this* reserved variable? Is there a reason (as Melissa suggested) that you are choosing to not use something like `dots <- list(...)` instead? Is it pedagogy? Programming language semantic curiosity?

Comment: Also do not forget to put your results in a list/dataframe/vector for you to print them out...

Comment: I know they are hard to see, but the ... on the left hand side of of the assignment are surrounded by backticks. So it is just a nonstandard name, not the reserved operation. See "Names and identifiers" under help(Quotes).  I acknowledge that if it were an assignment to a reserved word, having it throw an error should be no surprise.